# iPad:Size of my application in sandbox?

Tags: ipad

I have an application which stores bigger size records in sqlite db. I know every application stores in a sandbox separately. I want to know that, is there any size limit on iPad for every application in sandbox (or) size gets automatically extended in sandbox based on increasing application data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only to the limit of the devices flash-memory.